# why is reference variable type safer than pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

can someone explain why is reference variable type safer than pointer? i had already searched the internet but i am not able to understand why is reference variable type safer than pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a pointer as an argument the function code can change its type (AKA "casting"), and after that change the contents of the object the pointer points to with contents for another type. A big mess sticks around...

Comment: Can you explain how does it make a problem with operator overloading? @Ripi2

Comment: Where do you see a problem? Overloading is a C++ mechanism to allow the same function name with different arguments.

Comment: i had read in stack overflow that the introduction of reference pointers in c++ is to support  operator overloading. So why can't we use pointers for operator overloading?

Comment: Of course you can use pointers with overloading. Please, read a good C++ book. This is not the right place to learn general matters.